# What do $a,b$ designate here?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Dummit-Foote p.76

> Let $\phi:G\rightarrow K$ be a homomorphism.
>
> Let $G/\ker(\phi)$ be the set of fibers of $\phi$.
> Define $\phi^{-1}(a)+\phi^{-1}(b)\triangleq \phi^{-1}(ab)$
>
> Then, $(G/\ker(\phi),+)$ is said to be the quotient group.

I'm not really sure whether the text means the formulation above.

Can a quotient group have an empty set as an element?

If so, i think $G/K$ is not a group..

Am i understanding the context clearly?

I'm not sure whether $G/K$ is defined as "the set of inverse images of elements in $H$" or as "the set of inverse images of elements in $\phi(G)$".

Comment: The book does not speak about $G/K$, but $G/\ker(\phi)$

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen You are right it was a typo..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $a,b$ need to be in the image, otherwise there is no fibre. Then, $G/\mathrm{Ker \phi}$ is really a group, and is non empty (as all groups). Since $\phi(1)=1$, the identity of the quotient is $\phi^{-1}(1)$. The notation $+$ seems to say that the quotient is abelian, which is not always the case but could be in the case considered.

Moreover, $G/\mathrm{Ker \phi}$  is isomorphic to the image of $\phi$.

Comment: Thank you. What is this group specifically called, which depends on a homomorphism $\phi$? Maybe the quotient group with respect to $\phi$?

Comment: Normally, it is called the quotient of $G$ by $\mathrm{Ker} \phi$. I do not know any specific name with homomorphisms, usually people study quotient by subgroups.